# Convert PDF to series of images C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for free/open source library that will enable me to convert a PDF file into series of JPEG images.

I have previously accomplished this in Java using Apache PDF Box so i am looking for similar for ASP NET project i am working on.

The libraries i have found so far have limitations which i wasn't able to work with:

- Ghostscript - requires installation of separate application on server
- PDFSharp - extracts images from PDF, heavily dependent on PDF composition, didn't work with some files
- ItextSharp - apparently cannot convert PDF page to JPEG, similar problem as PDFSharp

Any guidance to a working library that enables me to convert PDF into series of image with a working example would be awesome.

In the mean time i will keep digging and if anything pops up I will add as answer.

Comment: You can try to use PdfiumViewer for this task. https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh thanks. I have no idea why someone down voted this question as its a legitimate query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code was working for me. It uses [PdfiumViewer](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer) library.

```
private static Image GetPageImage(int pageNumber, Size size, PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument document, int dpi)
{
    return document.Render(pageNumber - 1, size.Width, size.Height, dpi, dpi, PdfRenderFlags.Annotations);
}

private void RenderPage(string pdfPath, int pageNumber, Size size, string outputPath)
{
    using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(pdfPath))
    using (var stream = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
    using (var image = GetPageImage(pageNumber, size, document, 150))
    {
        image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am trying to get it working right now, the example you have requires you to advise what page to render, do you have anything that counts number of pages and iterates through them?

Comment: Have you tried to check what properties are available in the ```PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument```? There is ```PdfDocument.PageCount```.

Comment: Yea looking at that now. Can't get it working anyways, need to build the PDFium library and its spitting chips. Will keep looking for options. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to built this library? Have you tried to check Nuget repository? https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfiumViewer/

Comment: Yes used it from Nuget. When i ran it, it threw an exception, dependancy on  PDfium.dll

Comment: It depends from the native library pdfium.dll. This library included to to the NuGet package, but you need to copy it to the bin folder as it can't be added as reference. Please note that there are x86 and x64 versions.

Comment: Right. Reading up on it now to figure out where to find the file and where to place it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141335/discussion-between-uladzimir-palekh-and-aeseir).